# Changing position of div to float left,right alternatively using a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I need my images to float left and right alternatively and the current code that I'm using doesn't seem to work ,Not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm a newbie, So any help to point me in the right direction or a better logic to implement this would be helpful.

Much appreciated thanks in advance  .

```js
var positions = ["left","right"];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("CollegeIcon");
var len = positions.length;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
elements.style.cssFloat = positions[i];
}
```

```css
.CollegeIcon{
position:relative;
top:150px;
margin-left:30px;
margin-bottom:0px;
border:2px solid red;
}
.CollegeIcon:after {
    background-color: red;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height:34px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    width: 2px;
    left: 50px;
}
.CollegeIcon:first-child:after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='CollegeIcon'></div>
<div class='CollegeIcon'></div>
<div class='CollegeIcon'></div>
<div class='CollegeIcon'></div>
```

[image: result]

Comment: The property name is `float`, not `cssFloat`, and you need to set the style of the element, not the HTMLCollection. You could also take a look at [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class, using that you don't need JS at all.

Comment: @Teemu - `cssFloat` is the name in the DOM style object (like `className` for `class` and `htmlFor` for `for`) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration. `float` was a reserved word in JavaScript at one time, and before ES5 you couldn't use reserved word in a literal property name. So `style.cssFloat` and `style.float` and `style["float"]` all work now, but `style.float` was invalid in JavaScript prior to ES5.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, it looks like I've happily forgotten those days = ).

Comment: @Teemu thank you for the answer ,instructions provided by you helped me out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit unclear about your query but I hope you need something like this.

```js
var positions = ["left","right"];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("CollegeIcon");
var len = positions.length;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

elements[i].style.cssFloat = positions[i%2];
}
```

```css
.CollegeIcon{
position:relative;
top:150px;
margin-left:30px;
margin-bottom:20px;
border:2px solid red;
width: 20px;
height: 50px;
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class='CollegeIcon'>1</div>
<div class='CollegeIcon'>2</div>
<div class='CollegeIcon'>3</div>
<div class='CollegeIcon'>4</div>
```

Added some css and corrected below line in js:
`elements[i].style.cssFloat = positions[i%2];`

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

1. You're trying to use the `style` property on `elements` rather than on one of its entries. You need to index into `elements`.

   ```
   elements[i].style.cssFloat = positions[i];
   //      ^^^
   ```
2. You're not allowing for the fact there are more entries in `elements` than in `positions`. To wrap around in a zero-indexed list (like an array), you can use the remainder operator (`%`) with the length of the array. So:

   ```
   elements[i].style.cssFloat = positions[i % positions.length];
   //      ^^^                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

Updated snippet, but you have to look at the updated DOM to see that it works:

```js
var positions = ["left","right"];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("CollegeIcon");
var len = positions.length;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.cssFloat = positions[i % positions.length];
}
```

```css
.CollegeIcon{
position:relative;
top:150px;
margin-left:30px;
margin-bottom:0px;
border:2px solid red;
}
.CollegeIcon:after {
    background-color: red;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height:34px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    width: 2px;
    left: 50px;
}
.CollegeIcon:first-child:after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='CollegeIcon'></div>
<div class='CollegeIcon'></div>
<div class='CollegeIcon'></div>
<div class='CollegeIcon'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it in CSS with :nth-child?

```
.CollegeIcon:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
}
.CollegeIcon:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
```